# XamlParseException with amCharts on WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

I have tried to add a chart to my WP8-App, but there is some problem. I added a SerialChart with this small line of XAML-Code:

```
<charts:SerialChart ></charts:SerialChart>
```

This code is working fine when inserting it into an empty project. (Of course nothing is displayed, but also no exception).

But when adding it to my project - where I use Caliburn.Micro as MVVM Framework - I always get a

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Unknown parser error: Scanner 2147500037.
```

at the InitializeComponents-Method.

Has anyone also used amCharts and Caliburn together and had any problems?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It was easy to solve...

My project is splitted into serval sub projects and the xaml-pages were in such a sub project.

Now I just had to also add a reference to AmCharts in the main project and it worked.